# could not copy file name with space in scp ssh

Tags: php, ssh, scp

I could not copy the file with spaces in file name using ssh2_scp_recv() function.This is the filename testfile-03_23_15 11 02 AM.csv which actually stored in server.
my code is here

```
if ($file == "testfile-03_23_15 11 02 AM.csv"){

    if(!ssh2_scp_recv($connection,$remoteDir .$file, $localDir . $file)){
        echo "Could not download: ", $remoteDir, $file, "\n";
    }
}
```

Please help me if you know.
Thanks.

Comment: As a possible work around:  replace all spaces before copying

Comment: This is the filename testfile-03_23_15 11 02 AM.csv which actually stored in server. I cant change the file name in the remote server.

Comment: Use SFTP rather than SCP if you can. It's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

With phpseclib:

```
<?php
include 'phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php';
include 'phpseclib/Net/SCP.php';

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('bad login');
}
$scp = new Net_SCP($ssh);
$scp->get('file name with spaces');
```

Comment: sparkita thanks for reply. So you tell me that using  ssh2_scp_recv() function does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 ssh2_scp_recv($connection,"\"".$remote_file_name."\"",$local_path."/".$remote_file_name);
```

Source: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-recv.php)

It says: *Trying to get a remote file with spaces in its name? 
Never forget to use quotes in the remote filename, but never in the local one.*

Comment: Thanks for reply.. :) I tried this but it did not work..  My updated code is here                                                                                                               if ($file == "testfile-03_23_15 11 02 AM.csv"){
  
  $remote =  $remoteDir . $file;
  
  if(!ssh2_scp_recv($connection,$remoteDir ."\"".$file."\"", $localDir . $file)){
   echo "Could not download: ", $remoteDir, $file, "\n";
  }  }                                                                                                                              Any other solutions..