# Copy a file from a SFTP with a space in folder name

Tags: php

I'm trying to download a file from 2 different folders in a SFTP.
First file is in a directory with a " " in folder (ex. path/t o/file/a.pdf), second file is in a "normal" folder (ex. path2/to2/folder2/b.pdf).
If I try to download first file I have an error "unable to reach remote file", but with the second one I can download it correctly
This is what I'm doing

```
$connection = ssh2_connect(self::_URL_, self::_PORT_);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, self::_USER_, self::_PWD_);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
    if (!$sftp) {
       //Error 
    } else {
        $folder = str_replace(" ","\ ",$folder);
        $stringa = 'ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/path/{$folder}/pdf/'.$file;
        if (!$remote = @fopen($striga ,'r'))
        {
            throw new \Exception("Unable to open remote file: $file");
        }
    ...
    }
```

I've tried to use "pure" $folder and apply escapeshellarg, but nothing changes.
What I have to apply to that folder?

Thanks

Comment: Trailing Space are not allowed by os in the folder name. Therefore the folder can not have trailing space in the name.  Can you check by removing trailing space from you code.

Comment: Thanks, but the space is in the middle of the folder, I've updated the question

Comment: Ah..Okay try replacing Space with `%20`.

Comment: I've tried but nothing changes

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194011/could-not-copy-file-name-with-space-in-scp-ssh